# Compatibilidad de Bootstrap en IE!

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Se esta desarrollando una `app web`, las pruebas y demas se hicieron en `chrome`, y funciona todo perfectamente. Pero al probarlo en `Internet Explorer` que es el navegador oficial de la compañia este no funciona.

Esta es la app en chrome, y como se ve, esta contiene datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen es la app en IE, aqui no muestra los datos y cuando se da click en el boton de  `"Add item"` sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'openModalAdd' is undefined
```

Archivos de bootstrap utilizados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error lo genera solamente al precionar `Add Item`

Comment: Deberías mencionar la versión de Internet Explorer y el sistema operativo, [aquí dice que la compatibilidad está asegurada a partir de IE 10](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/)

Comment: Es IE 11, en sistema operativo 7...checare al pagina

Comment: Tal vez el problema no es con Bootstrap, lo recomendable sería tratar de aislar el problema, quitando las cosas no relacionadas para encontrar el origen del error